# What kind of fruit is this? It is the size of a small avocado or a plum

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

[image]

The flesh inside them seems ripe as it is squishy, and it gives off a strange odor. The smell at first reminded me of menthol. It's about the size of a small avocado, or a plum. A coworker of mine left a few on my desk before he left, but he didn't say what they were.

Comment: My cat definitely hates the smell. She reacted more strongly to this than to citrus.

Comment: Were did you find them? On a tree, on the market? Which country? Etc.

Comment: And please add an approximate size.

Comment: Might be a Kwini. Mangifera odorata

Comment: Please add more information about where this fruit comes from. (I upvoted your answer and downvoted your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a bit more research and asking a few friends, I found out that it was a **feijoa**, or **pineapple guava**. I think the ones in the picture aren't fully ripe yet, though.

[image: Feijoa]